# ElasticSearch - How to increase rank based on count of terms match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-6.8

Take the following `Author` example object (jsonified):

```json
{
  "name": "Author 1",
  "enabled": true,
  "books": [
     {"name": "book1", "popular": true},
     {"name": "book2", "popular": true},
     {"name": "book3", "popular": false}
  ]
}
```

What I want, is to rank `Authors` based on how many `popular` `books` they have.

Currently, I'm doing the following query:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {"enabled": true}
            },
            "should": {
                "terms": {
                    "books.popular": [true]
                    "boost": 3
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It works just fine, but it gives a 3 score boost if *any* book is popular (I think?).

How can I instead boost by *how many* popular books they have?